# Ember-data RESTAdapter without JSON payload

Tags: json, rest, ember.js, ember-data

In my Ember v2.7.0 app, I need to use backend endpoint which does not return JSON payload. But it behaves like REST endpoint, so I thought I would just use `DS.RESTAdapter` to fetch the data and convert the payload via `DS.Serializer`.

Created this little [Ember-twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/27638b7bd17853d22ff9e788502c6030?openFiles=serializers.application.js%2C), which just tries to fetch data with non-JSON payload. And it fails. As far as I can tell, it fails in `DS.RESTAdapter` code, trying to extract JSON from the payload. So that my serializer does not have a chance to process the data.

This seems a bit odd, because I thought that Serializer is the layer which is responsible for munching the payload.

1. Is it possible to use `DS.RESTAdapter` for querying non-JSON endpoint?
2. If not, what is the easiest way to have REST-like behaviour on non-JSON endpoint?

Comment: What format is the data the your endpoint returns?

Comment: @xcskier56 Nothing really nicely parsable: https://gist.github.com/MichalBryxi/76131c6985637e2b140a4e52dae40aef

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you'll need to do here is creating your own adapter that derives from `DS.RESTRAdapter` and then override its [ajaxOptions-method](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v2.7.0/addon/adapters/rest.js#L1065). There you could change its `dataType` to `text` instead. I imagine that they separated this into its own method for your exact purpose since it doesn't do much else.

The Ember Guides have a page about [customizing adapters](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.7.0/models/customizing-adapters/) that can get you started, based on the original code from the Ember repository it should probably be something like this.

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
import Ember from 'ember';

const {
  get
} = Ember;

export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
   ajaxOptions(url, type, options) {
    var hash = options || {};
    hash.url = url;
    hash.type = type;
    hash.dataType = 'text';
    hash.context = this;

    if (hash.data && type !== 'GET') {
      hash.contentType = 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';
    }

    var headers = get(this, 'headers');
    if (headers !== undefined) {
      hash.beforeSend = function (xhr) {
        Object.keys(headers).forEach((key) =>  xhr.setRequestHeader(key, headers[key]));
      };
    }

    return hash;
  }
});
```